# Why doesn't my Mask on a MaskedTextBox work?

Tags: c#, .net

I want a mask that will enforce an input of digit:digit, with additional optional digits on either side. Examples:

1:2

123:1234

So the mask I enter is 

`099\:0999`

I expect this is supposed to mean "A required digit, followed by an two optional digits, followed by literal `:`, followed by a required digit, followed by any three optional digits".

However upon testing the mask, the program happily accepts space in place of digits, so I am easily capable of ending up with something like `:2`, for example. The `MaskInputRejected Event` doesn't get raised either.

Am I doing something wrong? I understand that for `9`, a space is valid input, but for `0`, I expect a digit is required, and space is not valid.

Comment: Can you post some of your code? It may give a better idea of how to help.

Comment: The mask is entered in the VS designer. The designer produces this line for the mask:
`this.CapMaskedTextBox.Mask = "099\\:0999";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be either a bug in the control or an error in the documentation. The `0` in the mask will still allow spaces. Here is an article that will help you prevent the user from entering spaces.

[MSDN: How to disable the space bar in maskedTextBox?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8576de43-ead2-4ec4-a45e-78f11afa7411/how-to-disable-the-space-bar-in-maskedtextbox?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

And the relevant code is...

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == ' ' ) e.KeyChar = (char)0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. Being a bug or a documentation error certainly explains my issue. The example you've provided will prevent space as an input, but it doesn't prevent the user to leave space as part of the input either by deleting parts of the input, or leaving it blank (if the input field starts blank). Looks like I should write my own validation logic rather than rely on a mask in this case.